# change offsets.topic.replication.factor in kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, replication-factor

Previously, our Kafka cluster consisted of 3 brokers and offsets.topic.replication.factor was equal to 3. Now we have expanded the cluster to 5 brokers.

Can I affect the replication factor __consumer_offsets simply by changing offsets.topic.replication.factor to 5? Will this have an impact? Or should I still use kafka-reassign-partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it, yes, but it will not affect the topic actually.

You now need to use `kafka-reassign-partitions` tool to increase partition count and replica placement of each.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the replication factor to 5, it will not automatically update the replication factor of existing topics. It will only dictates the replication factor of new topics.To change the replication factor of the existing __consumer_offsets topic, you need to use the kafka-reassign-partitions tool to manually reassign the partitions and alter the replication factor of existing topics.